# Typescript issue with accessing global namespace functions in jasmine test

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, visual-studio-2015, jasmine

So this is a strange one that I have looked all over the internet for and have had no luck. I am adding in tests to a clients website with Jasmine, Chutzpah and Visual Studio 2015, so I am modifying existing code. So this is the issue, I have a client side written entirely in typescript and this makes calls to an API on the server. When I create the test files I cannot access functions in a global namespace. So the file I am trying to test looks like this, we will call this file foo.ts

```
foo.ts

    namespace foo { 

        export function isANumber(n) {
            !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFInite(n);     
        }  

    }
```

So this is one function I am trying to test inside foo.test.ts. This is my foo.test.ts file. I keep it in the same folder as the foo.ts just so I could see if it was a file placement issue.

```
foo.test.ts

/// <reference path="foo.ts" />

    describe("Foo Tests",
    function() {

        describe("Is A Number",
            function () {

                var isANumberTest;
                beforeEach(function () {      
                    isANumberTest= foo.isANumber;
                });
                afterEach(function() {
                    isANumberTest= 'undefined';
                });
                it("should return true if a number",
                    function () {
                        expect(isANumberTest(1)).toBe(true);
                    });

                it("should return false if not a number",
                    function() {
                        expect(isANumberTest('n')).toBe(false);
                    });
            });
     });
```

So the error I get when the tests run is ReferenceError: 'foo' is undefined and TypeError: Object expected. I can see in the debug that foo is undefined. When I tried wrapping the tests in the global namespace I just get the TypeError: Object expected. I can see that foo is now there but it doesn't have isANumber function in it. I am coming from a C# background into javascript. I am assuming that isANumber hasn't been created yet and that is why the tests can't find it. I am new to typescript, javascript and writing test in them. I am not sure if this is a compile issue and something is missing from a config file or if I am even writing the tests right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Are you loading the `foo.js` file? Referencing it just tells the compiler where to find the file for compilation but it has no effect in runtime, you must load the `js` file

Comment: Could you add some information on how you load/run your tests? This seems not to be an issue with TypeScript rather that the file, containing `foo` is not loaded :)

Comment: This is where my knowledge is lacking hahaha. With Jasmine and Chutzpah how do you load js files? I know typically it is done inside the specrunner.html file right.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add a script element to your `specrunner.html` to load your `foo.js`

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I was just using jasmine.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped nuget package so no specrunner was created and was assuming that the files got loaded when chutzpah was run. Never assume anything life lesson learned.